# Can i run the ionic v1 project when i have ionic CLI 4.6.0?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Now I have the latest version of ionic 4.6.0. My ionic version: 4.6.0.

When I tried the old v1 command:

ionic build ios

I received:

The build command has been renamed. To find out more, run:

ionic cordova build --help

Then run with,

ionic covdova build ios

That failed with this:

[WARN] Could not determine project type (project config: ./ionic.config.json).

```
   - For @ionic/angular projects, make sure @ionic/angular is listed as a 
     dependency in package.json.
   - For Ionic 2/3 projects, make sure ionic-angular is listed as a 
     dependency in package.json.
   - For Ionic 1 projects, make sure ionic is listed as a dependency in 
     bower.json.

   Alternatively, set type attribute in ./ionic.config.json to one of: 
   angular, ionic-angular, ionic1, custom.

   If the Ionic CLI does not know what type of project this is, ionic build, 
   ionic serve, and other commands may not work. You can use the custom 
   project type if that's okay.
```

Bad project type: undefined

Let me know If any thing I miss or need to change.

Comment: Additionally for future reference, if you want to create a new ionic v1 app, you need to add **--type=ionic1** when creating a new app **ionic start myApp blank --type=ionic1**

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, you just need to let the ionic cli know you are running an ionic1 project.

Open up the file "ionic.config.json" in a text / code editor.

In the json object, set type to "ionic1"

```
 {
  "name": "appname",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {},
    "gulp": {}
  },
  "type": "ionic1", //Set it here
  "watchPatterns": [
    "scss/**/*",
    "www/**/*",
    "!www/lib/**/*",
    "!www/**/*.map"
  ],
  "pro_id": "12345"
}
```

That should allow you to run and build ionic 1 projects.

If you do not have an ionic.config.json file, create on in the root of you directory and then copy and paste the above (you can remove pro_id if you are not using ionic appflow) and change the appname to the name of your app.

Comment: It's old, but.. You probably meant `ionic.config.json`.